# Url Re-Writing Issues with ASP.NET Application

Tags: asp.net

I added this code to my Global.asax, but Url rewriting doesn't work.

```
void RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("My-Account", "{page}", "~/myaccount.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("Login", "Login", "~/login.aspx");
}

void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in web config under system.web

```
  <system.web>
    <urlMappings enabled="true">
      <add url="~/myaccount" mappedUrl="myaccount.aspx"/>
    </urlMappings>
```

in code behind file write

```
Response.redirect("~/myaccount")`
```

This works 100%

Answer (score 0):

First: make sure that below codes exists in web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    ...
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
    ...
</system.webServer>
```

Second:make sure you are using application pool with .NET Framework4.0

Third:make sure that aspx files exists

Comment: thanks for answer. yes I have already. module tag in webconfig file and also i have aspx file in root directory.

Comment: not in root directory , ~/myaccount.aspx and ~/login.aspx exists?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register routes on application start, not begin request! Furthermore, your first rule beats any other. Order matters.

Comment: thanks for answer. but I have put my code in Application_Start method also.

Comment: @BhavinChauhan, care to elaborate then what do you mean by saying "it doesn't work"?